# Convert.ToDateTime producing different values in two server

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datetime

We have an vb.net 2.0 exe using Convert.ToDateTime running on windows 2003 server. 
Both of the server has Regional option set to English(Australia). But one of them is producting dd/MM/yyyy and the other one is producint MM/dd/yyyy.

It is now difficult to change the code as it has been running for a while. Does any one have an idea why it is happening and how to solve it.

Comment: If it's "difficult to change the code" this question probably belongs on superuser instead of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have different custom formats on servers. Anyway, you can always specify exact formatting in your code, probably it will be the best solution, because your application will work correctly on any server.

Comment: Hi Kirill, I have implemented a custom formatting for all of the dates. Thanks for  your suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

Use Control Panel to set the Regional settings to the same date format.